# Understanding the lshw output

Tags: centos

Can someone tells me if the fact that it's written "capacity: 42GiB (46GB)" means that I cannot insert a HD that is bigger than 42 ?

Because one of my HD is 72GB, and the "capacity" field is not listed.

Another question, it says "UNCLAIMED" but I have a "Vendor" field - so who is it then ? and is it normal that I have two different vendors for every socket ? ( FUJITSU / MAXTOR ) and also have different capacities ...

```
  *-disk:2 UNCLAIMED
       description: SCSI Disk
       product: MAP3367NC
       vendor: FUJITSU
       physical id: 1.1.0
       bus info: scsi@0:1.1.0
       version: 5608
       serial: UQL7P3C008AL
       capacity: 42GiB (46GB)
       capabilities: 10000rpm
       configuration: ansiversion=3
  *-disk:3 UNCLAIMED
       description: SCSI Disk
       product: ATLAS10K4_36SCA
       vendor: MAXTOR
       physical id: 1.2.0
       bus info: scsi@0:1.2.0
       version: DFM0
       serial: B2FA3PMM
       capacity: 34GiB (36GB)
       capabilities: 10000rpm
       configuration: ansiversion=3
```

Comment: Would you please try to clarify your question?  I'm really having a lot of trouble trying to figure out precisely what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

[It's actually fairly straight-forward](http://ezix.org/project/wiki/HardwareLiSter).

- **UNCLAIMED**: Means that there is no driver claiming this device. It is not a vendor field.
- **GiB vs GB**: Two different ways of listing the total capacity of a drive.

  - *GiB*: The capacity where the unit is div-by-1024 (true GB)
  - *GB*: The capcity where the unit is div-by-1000 (drive-marketing)
- **Vendor**: The PCI data for the device includes who manufactured the drive, this is that same field.

Comment: I'd be a little hesitant to call the SI, IEC, and IEEE definition of gigabyte "drive-marketing."

Comment: I understand the context of each field, but if the field is "UNCLAIMED" how is it that I have a vendor ? so the vendor is who ? the chassis ? if so, then how do I have two vendors there ?